# Why is the Splash Image Not Displaying?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why can't I get my Splash Image displayed on a Android device!

I have these kind of settings for Logo image display when the game starts.

[image]

If I press the Preview button then the Splash screen is displaying properly.

But in an actual Android build, it doesnt display.

So what is the solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot does not include what platform the settings are for. Make sure you are changing the correct Splash Image setting for the Android platform.

[image: Android Settings]